# Como soluciono Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: mysql

Quiero mostrar el nombre de el tengo este código:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']  = $_POST['usuario'];

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$pass = $_POST['contra'];

if(empty($usuario) || empty($pass)){
        echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('NO deje campos vacios'); window.location='Login.html';</script>";

exit();

}

$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","reservar");
$consulta1="Select nombre from usuarios where Correo='$usuario' and Pass='$pass'";
$consulta="Select * from usuarios where Correo='$usuario' and Pass='$pass'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
$resultado1=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta1);


$_SESSION['name1'] =$resultado1;
$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($filas>0){

    header("location:home.php");



}else{


    echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Usuario o contraseña incorrecta'); window.location='Login.html';</script>";

}



mysqli_free_result($resultado);

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['name1'] =$resultado1;` es la línea incorrecta.

Comment: pero como lo muestro el nombre

Comment: como lo muestro en otra pagina

Comment: es que en aqui $_SESSION['name']  = $_POST['usuario']; capturo el correo pero ahora quiero capturar el nombre de el

Comment: El código que compartes es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Mira lo que es y por qué debes evitarla.

Comment: La verdad es que el código tiene más problemas que sólo la inyección SQL (¿por qué usas dos consultas cuando con una te sobraría? ¿por qué asignas un resultset a un string? - el verdadero problema), pero deberías resolver los problemas de seguridad primero.

Comment: ocupo 2 consultas por que con esta consulta solo quiero capturar el nombre y mostrarlo  
$consulta="Select * from usuarios where Correo='$usuario' and Pass='$pass'";

Comment: No te lo tomes a mal, no estoy intentando criticar pero, para hacer un sistema de login, deberías dominar (o al menos tener idea avanzada de) conceptos de programación, seguridad y base de datos que, viendo el código que compartes, no tienes. No quiero decir que no debas hacer lo que estás haciendo, sólo que deberías avanzar más antes de plantearte hacer algo como lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: Haz caso de lo que te dice gente con más experiencia. Si los datos que quieres obtener en las dos consultas corresponden a la misma persona, es absurdo hacer dos consultas. Y lo de la seguridad es un tema que debería considerar muy seriamente. Saludos.

Comment: Las modificaciones que estás haciendo sólo perjudican la lectura y no ofrecen nada positivo a la pregunta. Las he revertido dos veces, por favor, no sigas haciéndolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es bastante claro , la variable que intenta asignar a la clave *name1* de `$_SESSION` es te tipo `Result`.

Para poder asignar tendrá que obtener los valores individuales de la consulta, hay muchas formas como `fetch_array`. Además tener en cuenta que solo necesita una consulta para el `login`.

**Código Final** *pero no la mejor opción*

```
$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","reservar");
/* Si desea obtener el nombre y correo sería , teniendo en cuenta el nombre de las tablas */
$consulta="Select nombre,correo from usuarios where Correo='$usuario' and Pass='$pass'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
/* Si Hay Resultados*/
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0){
    $fila = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    /* Asignamos A Sessión el valor de la columna Name*/
    $_SESSION['name']= $fila['nombre '];
    $_SESSION['correo']= $fila['correo'];
    header("location:home.php");
}
else{
    echo "NO HAY RESULTADOS";
}
```

> Como Recomendación ,**`el concatenar los valores es una muy mala practica`** , debería revisar una [Pregunta relacionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) con este tema y **`optar por usar desde ya consultas preparadas`**.

**Update** *Empleando PDO* para manejar consultas preparadas.

```
try { 
 /* Creamos La Conexión con PDO, modificar los valores respectivos*/
    $bd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=reservar',"root", "",array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sentencia = $bd->prepare("Select nombre,correo from usuarios where Correo=:user and Pass= :pass");
    $sentencia->bindValue(':user', $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentencia->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentencia->execute();
    if($sentencia->rowCount()>1){
        $_SESSION['name']= $fila['nombre '];
        $_SESSION['correo']= $fila['correo'];
        header("location:home.php");
    }
    else
        echo "NO HAY RESULTADOS";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
     /* Cancelamos La Transacción por si exista Error*/
    $bd->rollBack();
    echo "Se Presento Un Error :  " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: si gracias pero mi problema es el siguiente la consulta $consulta1="Select nombre from usuarios where Correo='$usuario' and Pass='$pass'"; la ocupo para capturar el nombre y mostrarlo en otra pagina pero me da ese error y no se como solucionarlo

Comment: @CarlosMendez no es necesario emplear dos consultas , en mi respuesta está corregido ese error, probar con mi respuesta.

Comment: ok gracias lo probare

Comment: y ocupo 2 consultas no para acceder al login ya que yo entro al login con el correo pero quiero mostrar el nombre de el por eso lo de las 2 consultas

Comment: @CarlosMendez revisar atentamente mi respuesta y los comentarios en ella, con una sola consulta obtengo el nombre y el correo y las asigno a `Session` para emplear donde usted desee.

Comment: Gracias funciono

Comment: como me puedo proteger de las inyecciones sql

Comment: me podrias dar un ejemplo en mi codigo por favor?

Comment: @CarlosMendez apliqué consultas preparadas  y `PDO` en mi respuesta , espero pueda ayudar. para más detalles revisar el link de la pregunta con una respuesta mucho más amplia.

Comment: 'if($sentencia->rowCount()>1) 
si pongo que sea mayor a 1 me da error, me dice que no hay resultados

Comment: asi que le puse que sea mayor a 0 y alli si funciona